# Можно ли автоматически делать запрос к указанному href?

Tags: yii2, bootstrap4, виджет, modal

Использую *yii2* и *bootstrap4* для него (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4)

В layout я прописал

```
<?php
    Modal::begin(['id'=>'simple-modal', 'size'=>'modal-lg']);
    Modal::end();
?>
```

Если где-либо в коде написать ссылку с `data-*` атрибутами такими как `-toggle` и `-target`, то вызовется это модальное окно

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/user/create" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#simple-modal">Создать</a>
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-то по-простому точно в таком же стиле указать атрибут `href`, чтобы при клике автоматически уходил запрос по-данному пути? Или это невозможно и нужно всегда делать вот так:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.modal-action', function () {
    $('#simlple-modal')
        .find('#modal-content')
        .load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

??

Answer (score 0):

У бутстрапа есть события типа show.bs.modal. После открытия модалки можно получить данные из элемента, который инициировал открытие и т.д. Если мы используем ссылку для открытия модалки, то нет смысла в href писать адрес, можно делать таким образом.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="#simple-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-url="/user/create">Создать</a>
```

Событие по открытию модалки

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
let modal = $(this);
let button = $(event.relatedTarget);
let url = button.data('url');

// грузим ресурс по адресу
});
```

Так не придется цеплять событие click на контейнер, что немного сэкономит ресурс.

Comment: Да, в чём-то есть смысл, хотя в целом получается то, что я описал в конце своего поста. Надо подумать

Answer (score 0):

Собственно два варианта:

```
<?= Html::a('Создать', 'javascript:void(0);', [
    'data-toggle' => 'modal',
    'data-target' => '#simple-modal',
]); ?>

<?= Html::button('Создать', [
    'data-toggle' => 'modal',
    'data-target' => '#simple-modal',
]); ?>
```

Comment: Вы не поняли вопрос. Суть не в том, как открыть модалку (это у меня написано в вопросе), а в том, как автоматом подтянуть туда данные указанные в атрибуте модалки